# Typo3: Using TCA type group with FAL

Tags: typo3, config

Is it possible to use FAL in TCA with the type group?

Based on the doc where say…

> elementBrowserType (string) (since TYPO3 CMS 6.0) Makes it possible to
>   set an alternative element browser type ("db" or "file") than would
>   otherwise be rendered based on the "internal_type" setting. This is
>   used internally for FAL file fields, where internal_type is "db" but
>   the element browser should be the file element browser anyway.

…I tried following:

```
'config' => array(
    'type' => 'group',
    'internal_type' => 'db',
    'MM' => 'sys_file_reference', // with and without this option
    'uploadfolder' => '',
    'minitems' => 0,
    'maxitems' => 99,
    'appearance' => array(
        'elementBrowserType' => 'file',
        'elementBrowserAllowed' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'],
    ),
    'max_size' => $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['BE']['maxFileSize'],
),
```

…and much more, but it wont work.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the API: `\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('media')` (taken from `core\Configuration\TCA\pages.php`).

http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/master/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_utility_1_1_extension_management_utility.html#ab95ff2f805d3ec462e869057339eee04

Comment: I think the special setting is that he wants a field of type group, not of type inline (for whatever reason...).

Comment: Yes, that's right. group. Is this possible at all? In the doc it sounds so.

Comment: It does not work this way any more. It might be possible to use the type group instead of inline (just have a look at the created TCA), but this is most likely not going to help you much. The new stuff might not be implemented for type group. You will have to check the code to verify this.